# No Angular change detection when communicating from IpcMain

Tags: angular, electron, ipc

I am building an app using **Angular / Electron**. In an Angular component I have a method - `handleData()` - that defines an Object - just straightforward Arrays, Strings, Numbers etc, no async calls or anything fruity like that. The properties of this Object are then used to create and populate the template using `*ngFor` and `*ngIf`.

Whilst developing I have a button in the component that when clicked calls `handleData()` directly and everything works fine - data is created, template updates to reflect it. Having got things set up like this I make a simple change so that *now* clicking the button sends a message via `IpcRenderer` (Using IpcService as described in [this article](https://dev.to/michaeljota/integrating-an-angular-cli-application-with-electron---the-ipc-4m18))...

```
onButtonClick(){
   this.ipc.on('test-response', (e)=>{
      this.handleData();
   });
   this.ipc.send('test-channel');
}
```

This is picked up in my `main.js` and I respond to it, sending a message back...

```
ipcMain.on('test-channel', (e)=>{
   e.sender.send('test-response');
});
```

In this case `handleData()` still gets called **BUT** now the UI no longer updates. I have to use `ChangeDetectorRef` and manually call `detectChanges` anytime I update a property that is linked to the template by `*ngIf` or `*ngFor`.

So my question is, what is different about calling a method on an IPC callback vs calling it directly?

Is this a sync/async thing? Zones? Scope issue?

Any thoughts gladly received.

Cheers all

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this using `NgZone`. As mentioned, I could have used `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` but I was having to call it after every update, not just in my main component but in all its descendants as well which seemed wrong.

I read some articles that suggested it might be a zone issue and so I had to finally try and learn what a zone actually is. I found [this article and the links within it](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) very helpful for getting a basic understanding.

Finally I injected `NgZone` into my component:

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone){}
```

Then I make sure the callback runs in the Angular zone:

```
onButtonClicked(){
   this.ipc.on('test-response', (e)=>{
   this.zone.run(()=>{
      this.testFunc()
   });
});
this.ipc.send('test-channel');
```

I'm not going to pretend I understand exactly why this problem occurred or why this fixes it. I assume that getting the `Electron` shell and `IpcMain` involved moves proceedings outside the Angular zone and doesn't go back in on the callback.

Answer (score 2):

Just use change detector.

```
constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef)

onButtonClick(){
   this.ipc.on('test-response', (e)=>{
      this.handleData();
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
   });
   this.ipc.send('test-channel');
}
```

Angular runs changes detection on:

1. User interaction (click, key event)
2. Change made to @Input
3. Change emmited to @Output
4. Changes made to public component variables

Remember, that all those changes must include changing of reference, not internat state of value.

For example

```
public user:User;

public someMethod(){
   this.user=new User(); // this will trigger change detection run
   this.user.name="Sebastian"; // this will not, 
   this.cdr.detectChanges(); // hey Angular, I made some changes - update view for me
}
```

Comment: That's what I have been doing but I have to call it every time I make a change to the data - when the data is created, when any child component is clicked and has to update. Basically I have no change detection at all any more. It works to use `ChangeDetectorRef`but really I want to understand why the change in behaviour when I start to use `Ipc` as opposed to a direct call from a button click?

Comment: Because clicking button internally lets angular know that some changes might have happen, and as result it runs change detection round. Angular refreshes view. When you make changes not by user interaction, you have to let angular know about it -  you do that by using change detection invokaction. Change detection round happens also when you update @Input or emit to Output or change reference in public component variable - remember that it have to be new assignment, not internat state change

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I solved it by handling synchronous event handling. You can do something like this.

In main.js.

```js
ipcMain.on("event_name", (error, arg) => {
 event.returnValue = "value you want to return"
})
```

In your browser file.

```js
let result = ipcRenderer.sendSync("event_name", "any value you want to send")
// result contains the callback value from main.js
```